# How is RegisterAppStateChangeNotification supposed to work?

Tags: c#, winapi

Microsoft documentation says:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/appnotify/nf-appnotify-registerappstatechangenotification

> Enables an app to register a callback function through which it can be notified that its library is going into or coming out of a suspended state. The app can use this information to perform any necessary operations, such as preserving state, that should be performed at that point.

I thought this meant that I could use this to get a callback if my app were to be suspended, but I do not seem to be getting one. I'm wondering, am I misunderstanding the purpose of this call, or is something wrong with my implementation? I do not see any examples of this in use anywhere on Google.

Here is my code. I have another app that suspends all threads associated with the app to put it in a suspended state.

My end goal is to be able to know if my app was previously suspended and resumed by another app.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("api-ms-win-core-psm-appnotify-l1-1-0.dll")]
    static extern bool RegisterAppStateChangeNotification(
            PAPPSTATE_CHANGE_ROUTINE Routine
        , IntPtr Context
        , out IntPtr Registration
        );
    
    IntPtr context;

    public delegate void PAPPSTATE_CHANGE_ROUTINE(bool Quiesced, IntPtr Context);
    public static readonly PAPPSTATE_CHANGE_ROUTINE stateChangedCallback = OnStateChanged;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegisterStateChange();
        txtProcessId.Text = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString(); //have this to make it easy to suspend the thread
    }
    
    public void RegisterStateChange()
    {
        RegisterAppStateChangeNotification(stateChangedCallback, IntPtr.Zero, out context);
    }
    public static void OnStateChanged(bool Quiesced, IntPtr Context)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("here!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Suspending the threads yourself will probably not trigger it? It has to be Windows doing it because it has to notify before suspending so the app can save state.

Comment: Interesting, that makes sense but means this will not help me. So far the best solution I have come up with is to run an interval every x seconds. On the next interval, I compare the current system time to the last known interval, if greater than x seconds then I assume I have been suspended. I recognize that the pause might not necessarily be another app but could be my own thread becoming unresponsive, but it’s the best I could some up with so far.

Comment: The API documentation is cryptic. The [Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/appnotify/) claims, that *"this header is used by The Windows Shell."*. From the looks of it it seems related to the application model introduced with Windows 8, that [allowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) for applications to get suspended. I don't know how (or whether) this can be enabled for regular desktop applications.